# Как сделать что бы сравнение не было чувствительно к регистру?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Допустим у меня есть

```
var word = 'Привет';
```

Как сделать что бы

`word == 'ПрИвЕт'` было `true`

Comment: перед сравнением приводите к одному регистру. Что-то вроде `if(toupper(param) == "MY_PARAM")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Переводить все в один регистр

```js
var word = 'Привет';
console.log(word.toLowerCase() === 'ПрИвЕт'.toLowerCase());
```

Или добавить метод сравнения непосредственно в класс `String`

```js
String.prototype.sameText = function(str) {
  return this.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase();
}
  
var word = 'Привет';
console.log(word.sameText('ПрИвЕт'));
```

Comment: `toLowerCase()` может быть [недостаточно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806552/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Приводите оба элемента к единому регистру.

```js
function equals(elem,base){
return elem.toUpperCase() == base.toUpperCase();
};
console.log(equals("Привет","ПрИвЕт"));
```

Comment: А как в js вообще выполняется операция ==? Разве она значения сравнивает?

Comment: Да, только она еще может `true` выдать при разных типах, в отличие от `===`

Answer (score 1):

`toLowerCase()` не всегда работает. Можно попробовать [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
[['Привет', 'привет'],
 ['flow', 'ﬂow'],   // D144
 ['å',  'å'],       // D145
 ['㎒', 'MHz'],     // D146
 ['I',  'ı'],       // Turkish
 ['BUSSE', 'Buße'], // D144 casefolding converts ß -> ss
].forEach(function(pair) {
  var [a, b] = pair,
   lowercase_cmp = a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase(),
   cmp = a.localeCompare(b, 'tr', {sensitivity: 'accent'}) === 0;
  console.log(`${a}, ${b} -> ${lowercase_cmp} ${cmp}`)
})
```

Строки в каждой паре в приведённых примерах эквивалентны согласно различным Unicode алгоритмам по сравнению без учёта регистра ([D144, D145, D146](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#G33992)).

`toLowerCase()` работает только для первой пары.  Решение с регулярными выражениями также не работает: `/flow/ui.test('ﬂow')`. [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) работает здесь для всех примеров, кроме `BUSSE`, `Buße` пары.